# Преобразование 6-7 значных координат в классические

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Вижу, например, в сервисе Я.Погода (осадки) значения полигонов передаются немного странным образом:

```
"coords": [
        [
          [
            1035271.26,
            2664706.97
          ],
          [
            1020799.73,
            2680395.39
          ],
          [
            1026365.71,
            2722711.73
          ],
          [
            1038610.85,
            2716659.49
          ],
          [
            1035271.26,
            2700934.7
          ],
          [
            1050855.99,
            2698516.91
          ],
          [
            1065327.53,
            2685225.74
          ],
          [
            1059761.55,
            2669532.51
          ],
          [
            1035271.26,
            2664706.97
          ]
        ]
      ],
      "id": 13,
      "bbox": [
        9.17,
        23.41,
        9.57,
        23.89
      ]
```

Гипотеза, что bbox - это ограничивающий прямоугольник в классических долгота/широта. Но сами значения coords странные, что это может быть? Какое-то преобразование Меркатора? Как перейти к нормальным координатам?

Делением на 100 000 получаем что-то иное.

Чисто случайно недавно видел в иной системе (3-d party) подобное, но тогда вопрос не успел зародиться.

Comment: Уточните, где именно вы получили такой ответ?

Comment: Например при запросе осадков https://yandex.ru/pogoda/moscow/maps/nowcast?from=main_maps_widget_top&le_Lightning=1 идут запросы вида:
https://weathermaps.s3.yandex.net/nowcast/1559800800/714e47b359c06d48dec4d05862ca7290_b0b84fa3/2/50_30_10.json

внутри json как раз данные об осадках на конкретное время в виде полигонов в таком виде

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к недокументированным внутренним интерфейсам Яндекс.Погода. У этого сервиса есть публичный API, и вам стоит воспользоваться им. https://tech.yandex.ru/weather/

Comment: Мне хочется получить положение всех осадков в текущий (и последующие) момент времени. Такого в api нет, мне нужны данные не по конкретной точке. Очевидно, что в api такого добавлять не будут

Comment: Очень похоже (99.9%) что это http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/Пересчет_координат_из_Lat/Long_в_проекцию_Меркатора_и_обратно (Меркатор/WGS84)